# C# class attributes, get them by index

Tags: c#, class, attributes, indexing

Is it possible to access attributes by index?

Take class Person for instance, which could have attributes "BirthNo" and "Gender". If I want to access BirthNo's value, is it possible in any way to write p.[0].Value or do I have to write person.BirthNo.Value?

```
Person p = new Person
//I have this:
string birthNo = p.BirthNo.Value;
//I want this: 
string birthNo = p.[0].Value;
```

Comment: They **are not attributes** but **properties**. To get them by index you have to use **Reflection**, in pseudo-code: `string birthNo = (string)p.GetType().GetProperties()[0].GetValue(p, null);`.

Comment: No; why do you want to?  I suspect there's a better way to do what you want that will not involve accessing properties by index.

Comment: @Adriano You should place your comment as an answer

Comment: @voo Too lazy to do it and to expand it with proper example and explanation... :)

Comment: @Adriano best not to use that: "The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies." from the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx

Comment: @Adriano Shut up and take my money! :)

Comment: @TimS. I agree, that's a good reason to do **not** post an incomplete answer! ;) If order is important he has to order them somehow, for example with `OrderBy` extracting a `DisplayAttribute` to check its `Order` property. Raw access by index is _good_ (as good as can be this use of Reflection) for a _dirty_ access by index within a `for` (or something like that).

Comment: @Adriano I once almost alphabetized the properties to get around this, but I decided that trying to use reflection made my code completely unreadable and nixed the whole design.

Comment: My bad, properties, not attributes. Been working with entities the last hour, must have gotten hung up on attributes :)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I really agree. Reflection may be The Solution but 99% of times there is something with a better design to solve that problem.

Answer (score 4):

`p.[0].Value` isn't correct c# code so you definitely can't write that.

You could try using [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx), but you'd have to write a lot of logic by your own, like that:

```
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: return BirthNo;
            default: throw new ArgumentException("i");
        }
    }
}
```

And invocation code would look this way:

```
p[0].Value
```

However, **it's horrible thing and you shouldn't even think about using it that way!***

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a string Dictionary inside your Person class and write the string values to it when the property is changed. Something like this:

```
class Person
    {
        Person()
        {
            properties.Add(0, "defaultBirthNo");
        }

        Dictionary<int, string> properties = new Dictionary<int,string>();

        private int birthNo;

        public int BirthNo
        {
            get { return birthNo;}
            set { 
                birthNo = value;
                properties[0] = birthNo.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

When you set the property

```
person.BirthNo = 1;
```

for example, you could then retrieve it using:

```
string retreivedBrithNo  = person.properties[0];
```

This is incredibly messy, and I can't think why you'd want to do it this way, but it's an answer anyway! :)

Comment: That would suffice if I was the one writing the class. I'm not, I'm just using it. After traversing the object with a

foreach (Person p in personList)
{
PropertyInfo[] properties = p.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo item in personProperties) 
{...


I'm getting i.e. item.name, in my case, BirthNo. I want the value of this persons birthno, and since p.item.name isn't possible to use, I was hoping to use index. 

Thanks for the reply though :)